# How to set content in PostAsync method

Tags: c#, .net, curl

When the method is called, it returns Status code: `not found`.  I'm sure that the uri is correct, so i think that the problem is the content. This is the api called by terminal:

```
curl --request POST 'https://api.uniparthenope.it/user/radius/auth' --data "user=xxxxxxxxxx" --data "passw=xxxxxxxxxx"
```

and this is my code:

```
public async Task<string> Login()
{
    client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.uniparthenope.it");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
    content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("user",Username),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("passw",Password)
    });
    content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "UTF-8";
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var response = await client.PostAsync("user/radius/auth", content);
    //return response.RequestMessage.ToString();
    return response.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Use Fiddler to capture a working and a failing request. Compare them.

Comment: Changed with content = new StringContent("user=" + Username + "&passw=" + Password) and now works, but only when fiddler is opened :| any suggestion?